# Baffling Run-time error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, have searched all over the place but can't seem to find a solution. I'm 
getting a `Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set` error. Does anyone know why?

Much thanks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Survey()

    'Name of the existing Word doc.
    Const stCoHydroSurveyTemplate As String = "Survey Template.docx"

    'Define Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdbmHeadLossTable As Word.Range
    Dim wdbmRevenueTable As Word.Range

    'Define Excel objects.
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rnHeadLossTable As Range
    Dim rnRevenueTable As Range

    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rnHeadLossTable = wsSheet.Range("HeadLossTable")
    Set rnRevenueTable = wsSheet.Range("RevenueTable")

    'Initialize the Word objets.
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "D:\Surveys" & stSurveyTemplate)
    Set wdbmHeadLossTable = wdDoc.Bookmarks("HeadLossTable").Range
    Set wdbmRevenueTable = wdDoc.Bookmarks("RevenueTable").Range

    'If the macro has been run before, clean up any artifacts before trying to paste the table in again.
    On Error Resume Next
    With wdDoc.InlineShapes(1)
        .Select
        .Delete
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Copy the Head Loss Table to the clipboard.
    rnHeadLossTable.Copy
    rnRevenueTable.Copy

    'Select the range defined by the "HeadLossTable" bookmark and paste in from the clipboard to the word doc "Survey Template".
    With wdbmHeadLossTable
        .Select
        .PasteSpecial Link:=True, _
                      DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
                      Placement:=wdInLine, _
                      DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End With

    With wdbmRevenueTable

        .Select
        .PasteSpecial Link:=True, _
                      DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
                      Placement:=wdInLine, _
                      DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End With



    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wdDoc
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    'Quit Word.
    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out your variables.
    Set wdbmHeadLossTable = Nothing
    Set wdbmRevenueTable = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    'Clear out the clipboard, and turn screen updating back on.
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    MsgBox "The Survey has successfully been " & vbNewLine & _
           "transferred to " & stSurveyTemplate, vbInformation


End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it throws the error? Also, a quick review of your code reveals you have two consecutive copies and two consecutive pastes. Go copy-paste-copy-paste instead. Find `rnRevenueTable.Copy` in your code and you'll understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The lines that give the error message are: 

Set wdbmHeadLossTable = wdDoc.Bookmarks("HeadLossTable").Range
Set wdbmRevenueTable = wdDoc.Bookmarks("RevenueTable").Range

Comment: Try changing the line to this format: wdDoc.Range.Bookmarks("HeadLossTable"). `Bookmarks` is a property of `Range`. That might be throwing the error.

Comment: Same error message.. Any other ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try calling the bookmarks by index number instead of name, like `Set wdbmHeadLossTable = wdDoc.Bookmarks(1).Range`.

Comment: @thunderblaster:  Same error message  :(

Comment: That is baffling (as advertised). Are you sure that `wdDoc` is being set correctly?  If you're not sure, you can add a breakpoint just after that step and check that variable.

Comment: Yes, wbDoc is set correctly. All suggestions to get this working are welcome - I'll try anything at this point.

Comment: I've tried running your code and get a compile error regarding the variable `stSurveyTemplate` should this be the constant `stCoHydroSurveyTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "D:\Surveys" & stSurveyTemplate)
```

Maybe you meant for it to be like this:

```
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("D:\Surveys" & stSurveyTemplate)
```

or this:

```
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\Surveys" & stSurveyTemplate)
```

What I noticed is that with the original code, it didn't throw an error and wdDoc was just set to Nothing. I removed the "sbBook.Path" and by mistake had an incorrect file name, and that did throw an error.